# In how many ways can $25$ elements be placed in $3$ disjoint subsets with $11$, $6$, and $8$ elements, respectively?

Tags: combinatorics

Three disjoint subsets are to be formed from a collection of $25$ items.   The first is to have $11$ elements, the second is to have $6$ elements, and the third is to have $8$ elements.   In how many ways can this be done?

**I know the solution to this question is 13,385,572,200** But I am not understanding how do I get to this answer? I know it has something to do with permutations.

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{25!}{11! 8! 6!} = 13,385,572,200
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Do you know how many $11$-element subsets can be selected from $25$ elements?

Answer (score 1):

The number of subsets with $k$ elements that can be selected from a set with $n$ elements is 
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$
where $n!$, read "$n$ factorial," is the product of the first $n$ positive integers if $n$ is a positive integer and $0! = 1$.  The notation $\binom{n}{k}$ is read "$n$ choose $k$."

Strategy:

1. In how many ways can a subset with $11$ elements be selected from a set with $25$ elements?
2. Once those $11$ elements have been removed, how many remain?
3. From the remaining elements, how many ways can a subset with six elements be selected?
4. Once those six elements have been removed, how many remain?
5. From the remaining elements, how many ways can a subset with eight elements be selected?
6. Apply the [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_principle).